# Inverse normalizing data of a dataframe directly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, normalization

I have a ata frame  `df` where all elements are in normalized form.which looks like this

```
        n_rgt_ps   n_th_ps  n_lft_ps  ...  w_rgt_ps   w_th_ps  w_lft_ps
0      0.051561  0.090402  0.071684  ...  0.011366  0.199501  0.066853
1      0.048586  0.131248  0.040074  ...  0.000129  0.196995  0.050425
2      0.049141  0.161515  0.061812  ...  0.000000  0.153019  0.050364
3      0.038548  0.076308  0.041129  ...  0.000000  0.130033  0.028748
```

However, I want to carry out denormalizing them or inverse transform them into original value. I know about `sklearn min maxscaler` but it only fit the data first and normalize it, then use inverse_transform to denormalize. How can I inverse normalize it directly here?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Without knowing the original data and how the tranform was made, there is no way of knowing what the original data was. Indeed, there is an infinite number of dataframes with the same normalized data. Take the following example:

```
csv_data1 = """A;B\n
1000;10\n
500;5\n
800;7\n"""

csv_data2 = """A;B\n
2000;20\n
1000;10\n
1600;14\n"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data1), sep=";")
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data2), sep=";")
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

which gives

```
 A   B
0  1000  10
1   500   5
2   800   7
      A   B
0  2000  20
1  1000  10
2  1600  14
```

Albeit the simplicicity of the example, it proves the point. We can certainly find other examples.

Now, applying

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

x = df1.values
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)

y = df2.values
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(y)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(y_scaled)
```

returns:

```
df1 = 
A_norm    B_norm
0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  0.0
2  0.6  0.4

df2 = 
A_norm    B_norm
0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  0.0
2  0.6  0.4
```

They are identical and yet, the original data is different.

Answer (score 0):

The `MinMaxScaler` transformation is based on applying a formula on the original data. This formula has to calculate **max** and **min** from original data.

Therefore, you cannot get the inverse without that knowledge.

Check out [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) for more information about the formula.